# GROUP_CONCAT too slow

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

Hello I added GROUP_CONCAT function to my query and that function killed my query :/. 
My query is :

```
SELECT u.username,a.user_id,a.id,a.text,a.lang as fromLang,b.lang as toLang,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id) AS translation_ids  FROM sentence as a 
   INNER JOIN sentence_relationship as sr ON 
    (sr.sentence_id = a.id)
   INNER JOIN sentence as b ON 
    (b.id = sr.translation_id AND a.id = sr.sentence_id) 
   INNER JOIN users as u ON 
    (u.id = a.user_id) GROUP BY a.id LIMIT 10;
```

What is wrong with that query ?

Comment: you could always fetch the IDs as a separate query.

Comment: Yep, I could , but I want to do everything in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query (somewhat formatted):

```
SELECT u.username, a.user_id, a.id,a.text,a.lang as fromLang, b.lang as toLang,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id) AS translation_ids 
FROM sentence a INNER JOIN
     sentence_relationship sr
     ON sr.sentence_id = a.id INNER JOIN
     sentence b
     ON b.id = sr.translation_id AND a.id = sr.sentence_id INNER JOIN
     users as u
     ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY a.id
LIMIT 10;
```

It is unclear from your question whether the `group_concat()` was added with the `group by`.  That could slow things down.

The `limit 10` is taking the first 10 `a.id`s that match (the `group by` does an implicit ordering).  If you do this with a subquery, it will probably speed up the query:

```
SELECT u.username, a.user_id, a.id,a.text,a.lang as fromLang, b.lang as toLang,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id) AS translation_ids 
FROM (select s.*
      from sentence s
      order by a.id
      limit 10
     ) a INNER JOIN
     sentence_relationship sr
     ON sr.sentence_id = a.id INNER JOIN
     sentence b
     ON b.id = sr.translation_id AND a.id = sr.sentence_id INNER JOIN
     users as u
     ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

This assumes that all the joins do work and match records.  If the joins are used for filtering, then you may get fewer than 10 rows back.

Comment: I tried to create a view with that query, but view doesn't accept subquery in FROM clause.I want a query that have same performance with old one.What should i do ?

Comment: @HalilBİLGİN . . . The only way I can think to do that in MySQL is to use two views.  One for the subquery and one for the outer query.